# Alternative way to change from a string literal to a raw string literal when reading in a file path

Tags: python, filepath, string-literals, rawstring

I am writing a function and my input parameter is the file path: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder

```
def read_folder(pth):
    for fle in Path(pth).iterdir():
        file_name = Path(pth) / fle
    return file_name
```

For me to use this function, I need to specify `r''` in the file path, ie.

```
read_folder(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder')
```

Is there a way where I can avoid specifying `r''` in the file path, ie. like the below and the code would work.

```
read_folder('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder')
```

The reason why I want to do this is so to make it easier for the user to just copy and paste the directory path into the function and just run the function. So it's more for ease-of-use on the user end.

Many thanks.

Comment: the `r` is used to escape the \ symbols which usually have a special meaning (character escaping) when `r` is not used. You can replace all \ with \\ and remove the `r`, that would also work.

Comment: Another alternative is using forward slashes (`/`) which work on both Windows and Unix-like OS's

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a raw string literal? Perhaps if you explain your motives, we could suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks all. The reason why I want this is so to make it easier for the user to just copy and paste the directory path into the function and just run the function. So it's more for ease-of-use on the user end.

Comment: This is an XY question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't really do that because without prepending `r` to your string there's no way python interpreter would know that your string contains `\` intentionally and not on purpose to escape the characters.**

So you've to either use `r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder"` or `"C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\IBM\New folder"` as *argument* while calling `read_folder` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the backslashes:

```
read_folder('C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\IBM\New folder')
```

Comment: Thanks.  The reason why I want this is so to make it easier for the user to just copy and paste the directory path into the function and just run the function. So if I do what you suggested, the user will need to put extra backslashes on each of the backslashes.

Comment: Why would your users be copy and pasting paths into the source file? That's not a very good workflow. Your script should read the path from standard input, or from a file, where the python escaping rules don't apply.